# prop doesn't update when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state-management, react-state

I am working on an application that needs to fetch some data asynchronously and save the state in the parent component but also pass the data reference to children. The problem is that once the data is loaded in the state, the props do not get updated to the new state. How can I make it so that the props get automatically updated when the parent state changes?

Here's my code:

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    contract: null,
    ethereum: null,
    user: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let ethereum = window.ethereum || null;
    this.setState({ ethereum });
  }

  getContainerClasses() {
    let classes = "container";
    classes += this.state.ethereum === null ? " invisible" : "";
    return classes;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Nav />
        <div className={this.getContainerClasses()}>
          <Intro ethereum={this.state.ethereum} />
          <Load />
          <Deploy />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class Intro extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        ...
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.props.ethereum);
  }

  getContainerClasses() {
    let classes = "container";
    classes += this.props.ethereum !== null ? "  " : "";
    return classes;
  }
}
```

As you can see in my example I am trying to log `this.props.ethereum` on a button click. Unfortunately it doesn't log out the data that is accessible in the `App` component (visible in the Chrome React Tools).

**Edit:** 
I misread my logs. The props are updating but the `getContainerClasses()` doesn't get fired when the state changes.

Basically what I am trying to do is to hide content while the data is not loaded yet and reveal it as soon as it is.

Comment: you didn't pass props on the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the moment your component mounts `windows.ethereum` hasn't been defined yet. It seems that `ethereum` is set in asyn way so your React component doesn't know when it happens. You'd have to add some event listener to react when `ethereum` is defined. You can see correct value in dev tools because there you have access to  object reference so you always see up-to-date value in dev tools.

Probably you use some `ethereum` lib which should include some API method allowing to react on moment when everything is ready and initialized. Below is psedu-code showing how you could achieve it:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    ethereum.addEventListener('ready', (ethereumObject) => this.setState({ethereum: ethereumObject}))
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure of that? Isn't it that as soon as react notices state changes it rerenders the affected parts? All I basically want to happen is that the `getContainerClasses` gets called again to update the classNames as soon as the `ethereum` state is updated.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But probably when you component is mounted `ethereum` isn't defined yet and as a result you set `null` in state. So the problem may be that when `ethereum` gets defined your component doesn't know about this so doesn't update state with new value. Please note that if `ethereum` gets defined in async way (let's say 100ms after your compnent has been mounted) your component will not see this update.